# Django Get full url path from app_name

Tags: django, url

there is a way to get full url from app_name ? like `reverse('myapp:bio')` inside class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm)

```
from django.urls import include, path
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view'),
    path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
]
```

i'm tryng to use it in MyForm(ModelForm) but i get that error

```
File "D:\Development\SiteDJCentral\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 607, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'website.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

print( reverse('myapp:bio') )
```

my form where i try call it

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

relase_date = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,  help_text='opzionale formato yyyy-mm-dd')

tags = OdsTaggerMultipleChoiceField( queryset = None, required=True, json_url= HttpRequest.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('myapp:bio' )) )
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse?

Comment: i'm tryng to use it in MyForm(ModelForm) but i get that error 
File "D:\Development\SiteDJCentral\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 607, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'website.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

    print( reverse('items:list', args=['Orléans']) )

Comment: Cam you add your form to the question?

Comment: What is a `OdsTaggerMultipleChoiceField, where does it come from and can you show the code for it? You should avoid url reverse in the body of your view or form classes, reverse_lazy should be use in those circumstances https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
from django.urls import reverse

reverse('main-view') == 'myapp/index/'
reverse('bio', kwargs={'username': UserObject.username}) == 'myapp/bio/<username>/'
```

Comment: cannot be used inside myForm(ModelForm)

Comment: You have changed the question! Why would you need that in `forms`? Urls are used mostly in `views` and `templates`.

Comment: i'm sorry, just adding details, bcz reverse works fine in other files

Comment: Now you don't have path with `name='items:list'`, so it cannot be like that. In `reverse` funtion you have to paste a valid `name` from a `path`. In your case it's only `main-view` or `bio`.

Comment: edited, you right my exeple code had some errors... however with right reverse('myapp:bio') error is HttpRequest.request.build_absolute_uri

Comment: Please, read carefully. Use that only LIKE THIS: `reverse('bio')`, NOT `reverse('myapp:bio')`